# <p> on img when hovering

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have a problem with my code.

I want to show information (`<p>`) about myself when I hover an image of myself.
I tried to paste the code in jsfiddle but even that failed...
I hope someone can help me with my code.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc7yyyqh/)

```
<div class="container pt">
<div class="row mt centered">   
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a class="zoom green"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="" /></a>
        <p>Hello iam Name</p> <!-- This P should be hidden and visible when the image is hovered -->
        <p>Name</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div><!-- /row -->
```

Answer (score 0):

add this css:

```css
.zoom p {
  display:none;
}

.zoom:hover p {
  display:block;
}
```

and move that name paragraph to be inside that `a` tag:

```html
<a class="zoom green">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="" />
  <p>Hello iam Name</p>
</a>
```

---

EDIT: 
As Mathius said in the comments, you could leave that p tag where it is and do

```css
.zoom:hover + p {
  display:block;
}
```

But you'd also need to do something like

```css
.col-lg-4 > p { display:none;}
```

and then you'd be introducing a potential problem because - what if the first `p` tag inside `.col-lg-4` is something you DON'T want to be hidden? *That* problem could be solved by adding a class to that name `p` tag and set the display:none; on it, like:

```css
p.name {
  display:none;
}
```

There are several ways to achieve the desired effect. I think the first example does this in the cleanest way, given the information given in the OP.

Comment: If you don't want to move the <p> to be inside the tag you could do something like: .zoom:hover + p {
  display:block;
}

Comment: The P shows beneath the img, and also with a low opacity, how can I fix this?

Comment: Your OP didn't specify you wanted that P to be anywhere else... you just said you wanted to show it upon hovering over the image. If you want the P to display somewhere else, you need to be more specific.

Comment: As the title says <p> on <img>, I want to show the <P> inside the <img> when hovering

Comment: ok... but **where** on the image? Taking up the whole area? At the bottom? At the top? What about text legibility when it's covering the image? Is that a concern? A good place to start would be adding `position:absolute; bottom: 0;` inside the css for `.zoom p `

Comment: Yes it does, I can see the <p> now in the <img>, as I use an opacity on the <img>, when I hover, the <p> tag also goes down, I tried giving the <p> tag a 100% opacity, but it stays at low opacity.

Comment: Try setting the opacity on the image, not the container (in this case, the `a` tag that wraps it is the container)